# Abstract Algebra: Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Find all of the distinct left cosets of <4> in Z18 and all the cosets of <4> in the subgroup <2> of Z18.

So The distinct left cosets of <4> in Z18 are
0 + <4> and 1 + <4>.

Do I have to list all 17 cosets in Z18 or since they are repetitive, the two I have listed cover everything?

Now, all of the cosets of <4> in the subgroup <2> of Z18 is just <2> because <2>=<4>={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16}.

Comment: I take the word "distinct" in the question as meaning that you should not list repetitions.

Comment: Ok. That's what I thought too. I was double checking. Now for the second part since it doesn't state distinct cosets, just all coset, then do I have to list all of the cosets of <4> that produce <2>. For example, 0 + <4>, 2 + <4>, 4 + <4>, ...

Comment: I'd assume that the omission of "distinct" in the second question was not intended to make you list the same coset 9 times. The purpose of questions like this should be to help you learn mathematics, not to bore you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the left cosets of $\langle 4\rangle \in \mathbb Z_{18}$ are given by $\langle 4\rangle$ and $1 + \langle 4\rangle$.

In the second case, the number of cosets of $\langle 4\rangle$ in $\langle 2\rangle$ is one: namely $\langle 4 \rangle = \langle 2\rangle$.

Note that in abelian groups, we can speak of the number of *cosets*, because left and right cosets are indistinguishable.